# Relay Command not firing on menu item click

Tags: wpf, mvvm, menuitem, commandbinding

My View

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu x:Name="Conn_Context_button" Style="{StaticResource LeftContextMenuStyle}">
     <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource LeftContextMenuItemStyle}" Header="{x:Static properties:ResourceWrapper.Dashboard_Connection_Delete}" Click="MenuItem_DeleteConnection_Click" />
     <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource LeftContextMenuItemStyle}" Header="{x:Static properties:ResourceWrapper.Dashboard_Connection_Refresh}" Command="{Binding MyViewModel.RefreshCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu>
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
 public RelayCommand RefreshCommand { get; set; }
  RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshConnection);
    private void RefreshConnection(object sender)
    {
       //My Logic
    }
```

Here RefreshCommand is not firing when i click the refresh menu item

Comment: Maybe Use ICommand instead?

Comment: Maybe the datacontext is incorrect, check for binding errors in the output. If `MyViewModel` is the datacontext, `Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}` will solve this.

Comment: It ist not so easy: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994241/mvvm-binding-command-to-contextmenu-item

Comment: @Natxo I have already set MyViewModel as datacontext. and also tried `Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}` But the result is same.. it didnt throw any error. but nothing happens when i click the menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a good example, take a look to this [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943081/relaycommand-not-firing-on-menuitem-click-wpf-mvvm).

Here's a simple piece of code taken from one of my current projets:

```
private void PrepareCommands()
{
    RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshCommandMethod);
    AddConfigurationCommand = new RelayCommand(AddConfigurationCommandMethod, param => CanAddConfiguration);
    EditConfigurationCommand = new RelayCommand(EditConfigurationCommandMethod, param => CanEditConfiguration);
    RemoveConfigurationCommand = new RelayCommand(RemoveConfigurationCommandMethod, param => CanRemoveConfiguration);
}
```

where the commands are

```
#region Commands

public ICommand AddConfigurationCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand EditConfigurationCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand RemoveConfigurationCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; set; }

#endregion
```

Bindings are

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
    <Button Template="{StaticResource AddButton}" Command="{Binding AddConfigurationCommand}"  Margin="3,0" />
    <Button Template="{StaticResource EditButton}" Command="{Binding EditConfigurationCommand}" Margin="3,0" />
    <Button Template="{StaticResource DeleteButton}" Command="{Binding RemoveConfigurationCommand}" Margin="3,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

As Jan Walczak said above, try to use `ICommand` instead of `RelayCommand`. If you have created your own `RelayCommand`, don't forget to inherit from `ICommand`.